# Http GET method to Https?

Tags: json, web-services, ssl, android-studio, https

Sorry for my noob question but I have this code to get JSON information about my database from my web service:

```
public static JSONObject readJsonFromUrl(String url) throws IOException, JSONException {
    InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
    try  {
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        String jsonText = readAll(rd);
        return new JSONObject(jsonText);
    } finally {
        is.close();
    }
}

private static String readAll(Reader rd) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int cp;
    while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) {
        sb.append((char) cp);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

I've just bought a SSL certificate, and i have to pass my GET method code from HTTP to HTTPS, how can i do it?

This is my TLSSocketFactory to enable TLS 1.1 and 1.2:

```
public class TLSSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {

private SSLSocketFactory internalSSLSocketFactory;

public TLSSocketFactory() throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    context.init(null, null, null);
    internalSSLSocketFactory = context.getSocketFactory();
}

@Override
public String[] getDefaultCipherSuites() {
    return internalSSLSocketFactory.getDefaultCipherSuites();
}

@Override
public String[] getSupportedCipherSuites() {
    return internalSSLSocketFactory.getSupportedCipherSuites();
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(Socket s, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException {
    return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(s, host, port, autoClose));
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(String host, int port) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
    return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port));
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(String host, int port, InetAddress localHost, int localPort) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
    return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port, localHost, localPort));
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(InetAddress host, int port) throws IOException {
    return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port));
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(InetAddress address, int port, InetAddress localAddress, int localPort) throws IOException {
    return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(address, port, localAddress, localPort));
}

private Socket enableTLSOnSocket(Socket socket) {
    if(socket != null && (socket instanceof SSLSocket)) {
        ((SSLSocket)socket).setEnabledProtocols(new String[] {"TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2"});
    }
    return socket;
}
}
```

With my POST method I created a instance of my TLSSocket factory and applied to my POST method like this:

```
TLSSocketFactory tlsSocketFactory = new TLSSocketFactory();
        HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setSSLSocketFactory(tlsSocketFactory);
```

But, my question is.. **How can i do it the same for my GET method?**

Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 1):

To set your `TLSSocketFactory` for use given your `url`, *assuming it is an HTTPS URL*, you might be able to use:

```
HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
conn.setSSLSocketFactory(tlsSocketFactory);
```

Just the same as you do for `POST`, `PUT`, *etc*.  To explicitly state that you want this `conn` to use `GET`:

```
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
```

or `"POST"` or `"PUT"` as needed.  Then:

```
conn.connect();
InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
```

and read your JSON data from that `InputStream`.

Hope this helps!